# При выводе Maatwebsite\Excel в формате html пропадают картинки из документа (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

Такая проблема, в laravel подключил Maatwebsite\Excel через composer (используется phpExcel). При выводе можно указывать в каком формате требуется вывод:

```
$excel = Excel::load($filePath);
$excel->export('html');
```

В вывод (если выводить не в excel формате) не попадают картинки из файла. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение проблемы, напишу если вдруг у кого-нибудь возникнет.
Лучше всего будет использовать `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` вместо `phpoffice/phpexcel`, так как phpexcel более не поддерживается и в нем как раз содержится внутренняя ошибка при выводе картинок (Переделать код под новую библиотеку не сложно, у меня заняло 15 минут).
Если же Вы все-таки не можете использовать phpspreadsheet, то необходимо поставить fork с исправлением данной ошибки. Исправление есть здесь
https://github.com/Tomino2112/PHPExcel/commit/e7b4b71172f5f79d233ec2be82c70e873ca2faec
В случае установки phpspreadsheet пользоваться Maatwebsite\Excel не получится